# Making a 'plaintext' string safe from cracking?

Tags: security, delphi

Supposing I have an important password somewhere in my program and I want to make it safer, ex:

```
ftp.password := 'mypassword';
```

About 8 years ago I use to 'crack stuff' for fun, so I found me stuff like that quite easily by using OllyDbg.

What I need to know is if there is a way to make this thing safe from prying eyes. I thought about storing the password directly into the component, but then again don't know if it would do any good.

Comment: Don't store passwords. Hash and then store the password.

Comment: @David Heffernan - That would not work if those passwords need to be sent to another app/service (e.g. connecting to an FTP server).

Comment: True. But my point is that if he needs to send a password to an FTP server, hashing the password for storage will not work. If he wants to *accept* passwords form the user, yes: hash and compare hashes.

Comment: The subject line isn't exactly an oxymoron, but the two notions "naked string" and "safe from cracking" are utterly incompatible, right?

Comment: @Nick pre-selecting words from a text and comparing them to something can make it out to be whatever you want it to be. Isn't that what they do with the bible after all?

Comment: Please update question to explain if the user knows the password, and you're just trying to store it safely so if the computer is lost, the password can't be easily recovered, or if the user must not know the password. Also, do you have the ability to generate and remove ftp accounts? If you provide explicit details about the system, we can provide optimal solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just don't do it. If you want to keep a password safe, don't put it in the program. You can ask the user for it if the program is interactive. If not, you should set up some kind of non-password-based authentication for the program to use.

If you must embed the password in the program, the rule is very simple -- never give the program to anyone who is not supposed to be able to do anything the password allows them to do.

Comment: Mmm, perhaps if I make an user for the program, that'd be a little safer, even if someone does get it, they won't go very far with it.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst the answer that you just shouldn't do this is correct, in practise there are occasions when the real world forces you hand.  In the one or two instances where I've been forced into something like the approach I've used is to code a function that will generate a known password from scratch using some mathematical formula - for instance the first letter of the English words for the first 8 digits of PI in reverse order. Of course this can still be cracked, but it makes the task a little harder and should discourage casual browsers.

Of course if you're really using FTP (not SFTP) you're passing the password in plain text across the network anyway.  I'd be more concerned with that initially - it's a much more obvious attack vector.

Comment: +1 I'd sniff the network traffic before I'd open my debugger. It's just easier.

Answer (score 4):

While I entirely agree with David Schwartz (you shouldn't embed any passwords inside a program directly), it is possible to make it *more difficult* for anyone to locate it.

Instead of defining the string in one piece, you can build the string procedurally. This way the string as a whole is never stored in one piece inside your executable, making it more difficult to find.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, nice idea.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply not a problem that cryptography can solve.   The only way to protect this value is to rely upon the user access control provided by your operating system.  Make sure the file's permissions are limited as much as possible. `chown user:user file` then `chmod 400 file`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way - it keeps it safe from curious people with a hex viewer, but of course won't work with advanced techniques at runtime:

```
function GetA: string;
begin
  Result := #$109#$121#$122;  // 'myp'
end;

function Getb: string;
begin
  Result := #97#$115#$115#$119;  // 'assw'
end;

function GetC: string;
begin
  Result := #$111#$114#$100;  // 'ord'
end;

procedure TForm1.Whatever;
begin
  ftp.Password := GetA + GetB + GetC + GetD;
end;
```

As I said, it's not secure from someone setting a break during the code execution with a debugger and inspecting the `ftp.password` in memory after it's set, but it's safe from a hex viewer. I usually set the designtime value of the `ftp.password` to something like `DoyouthinkImthatstupid?` for those who like to try, though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could Encrypt the string, and Decrypt it back when you read it?

But even then, as others have said, storing a password internally in the Application is not a good idea.

Even if you Encoded or Encrypted the string it is not going to be safe from determined people.